# Missing types, namespaces, directives, and assembly references

Tags: q#

I use `VS Code` for `C#` and `Unity3D` and `TypeScript` and `Angular` and `Python` programming, so I have pretty much every required extension, including the `.NET Framework` and `Core` as well as the `Quantum Development Kit (QDK)` plus the `Q# Interoperability Tools` and also `C#` and `Python` extensions for `VS Code`.

I have devised the following steps to create my first quantum Hello World based on a few tutorials:

```
$ dotnet --version
$ dotnet --list-sdks
$ dotnet --list-runtimes

$ dotnet new globaljson                                     # Create a "global.json" file in your current directory folder.  
$ dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 3.1.416 --force       # Change the current SDK version of your project.

$ dotnet new -i Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates
$ dotnet new -i "Microsoft.Quantum.ProjectTemplates::0.2-*"

# First, create a Q# application and a .NET host, and then make a call to Q# from the host.
# Create a project for your Q# library and for the .NET host that will call
# into the operations and functions defined in your Q# library.

$ dotnet new classlib -lang Q# -o quantum                         # Create a new Q# class-library project.
$ dotnet new console -lang C# -o host                             # Create a new C# console project.

$ cd host                                                         # Navigate into the C# host directory.
$ dotnet add reference ../quantum/quantum.csproj                  # Add your Q# class-library project as a reference to your C# console project.

$ cd ..                                                           # Exit the C# host directory.
$ dotnet new sln -n quantum-dotnet                                # Create a new solution for both projects.
$ dotnet sln quantum-dotnet.sln add ./quantum/quantum.csproj      # Add the Q# class-library project to the solution.
$ dotnet sln quantum-dotnet.sln add ./host/host.csproj            # Add the C# host project to the solution.

# The -o or --output command specifies the location to place the generated output.
```

**However**, as soon as this is all done, I get the following load of errors:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

---

Here is some additional info:

```
$ dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.416 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.404 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

$ dotnet --version  
3.1.416

$ dotnet restore
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\Users\Muhy\Dropbox\Q\Q#-programs\Qtest\quantum\quantum.csproj (in 484 ms).
  Restored C:\Users\Muhy\Dropbox\Q\Q#-programs\Qtest\host\host.csproj (in 782 ms).
```

---

When I run `dotnet build`, I get the following:

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.2+b60ddb6f4 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Determining projects to restore...
All projects are up-to-date for restore.
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0' was not found.
- The following frameworks were found:
3.1.22 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
5.0.13 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
- https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
C:\Users\Muhy.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.development.kit\0.2.1802.1603-preview\build\Microsoft.Quantum.Development.Kit.targets(17,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet C:\Users\Muhy.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.development.kit\0.2.1802.1603-preview\build../tools/qsc/qsc.dll --input "Operation.qs" --references "C:\Users\Muhy.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.canon\0.2.1802.1603-preview\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Quantum.Canon.dll" "C:\Users\Muhy.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.development.kit\0.2.1802.1603-preview\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Quantum.MetaData.dll" "C:\Users\Muhy.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.development.kit\0.2.1802.1603-preview\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Quantum.Primitives.dll" "C:\Users\Muhy.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.development.kit\0.2.1802.1603-preview\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Common.dll" "C:\Users\Muhy.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.development.kit\0.2.1802.1603-preview\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core.dll" "C:\Users\Muhy.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.development.kit\0.2.1802.1603-preview\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.QCTraceSimulatorRuntime.dll" "C:\Users\Muhy.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.development.kit\0.2.1802.1603-preview\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Simulators.dll" --outputpath obj\qsharp\src" exited with code -2147450730. [C:\Users\Muhy\Dropbox\Q\Q#-programs\Qtest\quantum\quantum.csproj]

Build FAILED.

C:\Users\Muhy.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.development.kit\0.2.1802.1603-preview\build\Microsoft.Quantum.Development.Kit.targets(17,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet C:\Users\Muhy.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.development.kit\0.2.1802.1603-preview\build../tools/qsc/qsc.dll --input "Operation.qs" --references "C:\Users\Muhy.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.canon\0.2.1802.1603-preview\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Quantum.Canon.dll" "C:\Users\Muhy.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.development.kit\0.2.1802.1603-preview\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Quantum.MetaData.dll" "C:\Users\Muhy.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.development.kit\0.2.1802.1603-preview\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Quantum.Primitives.dll" "C:\Users\Muhy.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.development.kit\0.2.1802.1603-preview\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Common.dll" "C:\Users\Muhy.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.development.kit\0.2.1802.1603-preview\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core.dll" "C:\Users\Muhy.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.development.kit\0.2.1802.1603-preview\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.QCTraceSimulatorRuntime.dll" "C:\Users\Muhy.nuget\packages\microsoft.quantum.development.kit\0.2.1802.1603-preview\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Simulators.dll" --outputpath obj\qsharp\src" exited with code -2147450730. [C:\Users\Muhy\Dropbox\Q\Q#-programs\Qtest\quantum\quantum.csproj]
0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)

---

When I also build the project (`dotnet build quantum-dotnet.sln` and `dotnet build ./host/host.csproj`) I get the same errors.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this setup. What happens when you try to build your solution or the host project? i.e.: `dotnet build quantum-dotnet.sln` or `dotnet build ./host/host.csproj`?

Comment: @Elcapi Thanks for your reply. I have added the output of the builds that you ask about. Please see my edited post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the problem now. The command:

```
dotnet new -i "Microsoft.Quantum.ProjectTemplates::0.2-*"
```

installed version `0.2.1802.1603-preview`, which is many years old. Our latest version is `0.22.187631`.

Is there any specific reason you decided to specify a version number when installing the templates package? This should work:

```
dotnet new -i "Microsoft.Quantum.ProjectTemplates"
```

My recommendation is to run:

```
dotnet new --update-apply
```

to update all your project templates. After this, re-create the projects. Let us know if this works.

Comment: Bless you! It fixed all the errors. It now works like a charm. Much appreciated :-)